# Preg_replace with "-" once

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have following symbols which preg_replace replaces:

```
$replace = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/';
```

in my code I use:

```
print "<a href='".preg_replace($replace, '-', $p->name)."-pr-".$p->id.".html'>";
```

The result of the above is the following:

```
Apple-iPad-2-Wi-Fi---3G-16GB-White-Tablet---MC982NFA-p-110341697.html
```

What do I have to do in order for it to only replace the symbols stated above with only one "-", like the below example:

```
Apple-iPad-2-Wi-Fi-3G-16GB-White-Tablet-MC982NFA-p-110341697.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `+` to the expression, to match one **or more** occurences:

```
$replace = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/';
```

Although the expression can be made shorter as:

```
$replace = '/[\W_]+/';
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: @Truth Yours would work though, it's not a stupid answer... :-D

Comment: No, but 1 regex is better than 2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$replace = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/';`.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/\.\s|[^a-zA-Z\.\-0-9]+/", "-", $raw)
```

It will replace `.` and White Space or Any other Char with -
So the Dot and Space will Replace with Single Dash

Answer (score 0):

Add another replacement to replace any repeating - with a single -.

```
preg_replace("|-+|g", "-");
```